How can I maintain row selections in a DataGrid with pagination and search in React?
I'm working on a DataGrid component in React that includes pagination and search functionalities. My goal is to ensure that row selections (checkboxes) persist even when navigating through pages or performing searches. Currently, the row selections do not retain their state when the data updates.
Setup:
Component: DataTableSearch
Dependencies: react-query, @mui/material, @mui/x-data-grid
State Management: Using useState and useEffect to manage row selections and data updates.
What I’ve Tried:
Managing Selected Row IDs: I use a Set to track selected row IDs and attempt to update this set when data or selected items change.
Storing Selected IDs with useRef: I use useRef to persist selected row IDs across re-renders.
Updating State and Ref: The state and selectedRowIdsRef are updated based on changes in filteredRows and selectedItems.
What I Expected:
I expected that the selected rows would remain checked across pagination and search operations, preserving user selections as the data changes.
What Actually Resulted:
The selected rows are not retained. When users paginate or search, the previously selected rows become unchecked, and the state does not accurately reflect the selections.


import { getItemBypageFiltered } from "@/actions/accounting/items/get-item-by-page-filtered";
import { Box, Grid, Skeleton, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

type DataTableSearchProps<T> = {
    rows: Array<T>;
    columns: Array<GridColDef>;
    loading: boolean;
    error: Error | null;
    rowCount?: number;
    checkboxSelection?: boolean;
    page?: { page: number; pageSize: number; };
    setPage?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{ page: number; pageSize: number; }>>;
    onRowDoubleClick?: (row: T) => void;
    paginationMode?: 'client' | 'server';
    getRowId?: (row: T) => string;
    onSelectionChange?: (selectedIds: string[]) => void;
    selectedItems?: { id: string; name: string }[];
};

export function DataTableSearch<T>({
    columns,
    rows,
    loading,
    page = { page: 0, pageSize: 200 },
    setPage,
    rowCount,
    checkboxSelection = false,
    onRowDoubleClick,
    paginationMode = 'server',
    getRowId,
    onSelectionChange,
    selectedItems = []
}: DataTableSearchProps<T>) {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const [filteredRows, setFilteredRows] = useState<Array<T>>(rows);
    const [selectedRowIds, setSelectedRowIds] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set());
    const selectedRowIdsRef = useRef<Set<string>>(new Set());

    const { data, isLoading, isError, error: queryError } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['itemgroups', page.page, searchTerm],
        queryFn: () => getItemBypageFiltered(page.page, page.pageSize, searchTerm),
        enabled: searchTerm.length > 0 || paginationMode === 'server',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data?.data) {
            setFilteredRows(data?.data.data as unknown as T[]);
        } else {
            setFilteredRows(rows);
        }
    }, [data, rows]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const currentRowIds = new Set(filteredRows.map(row => getRowId ? getRowId(row) : (row as any).id as string));
        const updatedSelectedIds = new Set([...selectedRowIdsRef.current]);
        setSelectedRowIds(updatedSelectedIds);
        selectedRowIdsRef.current = updatedSelectedIds;
    }, [filteredRows, getRowId]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (setPage) {
            setPage(prev => ({ ...prev, page: 0 }));
        }
    }, [searchTerm, setPage]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const selectedIds = selectedItems.map(item => item.id);
        const validSelectedIds = selectedIds
            .filter(id =>
                filteredRows.some(row => {
                    const rowId = getRowId ? getRowId(row) : (row as any).id;
                    return rowId === id;
                })
            );
        const newSelectedRowIds = new Set(validSelectedIds);
        setSelectedRowIds(newSelectedRowIds);
        selectedRowIdsRef.current = newSelectedRowIds;
    }, [filteredRows, selectedItems, getRowId]);

    const handleSelectionModelChange = (selectionModel: any) => {
        const newSelectedRowIds = new Set<string>(selectionModel);
        const updatedSelectedIds = new Set([...selectedRowIdsRef.current, ...newSelectedRowIds]);
        setSelectedRowIds(updatedSelectedIds);
        selectedRowIdsRef.current = updatedSelectedIds;
    };

    const handleSearchChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (onSelectionChange) {
            onSelectionChange([...selectedRowIds]);
        }
    }, [selectedRowIds, onSelectionChange]);

    if (isError || queryError) {
        return (
            <Box
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    height: "100%",
                    width: "100%",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                }}
            >
                <Typography variant="h5">Error al obtener datos</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">Mensaje: {queryError?.message}</Typography>
            </Box>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Box>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12} sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
                <TextField
                    label="Buscar"
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth
                    margin="normal"
                    value={searchTerm}
                    onChange={handleSearchChange}
                />
            </Grid>
            {loading || isLoading ? (
                <>
                    {[...Array(6).keys()].map((index) => (
                        <Skeleton key={index} height={64} />
                    ))}
                </>
            ) : (
                <Box style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
                    <DataGrid
                        rows={filteredRows}
                        columns={columns}
                        pageSizeOptions={[6, 12]}
                        checkboxSelection={checkboxSelection}
                        rowCount={rowCount}
                        paginationMode={paginationMode}
                        paginationModel={page}
                        onPaginationModelChange={setPage}
                        onRowDoubleClick={(e) => onRowDoubleClick && onRowDoubleClick(e.row as T)}
                        getRowId={getRowId ? getRowId : (row) => row.id as string}
                        rowSelectionModel={[...selectedRowIds]}
                        onRowSelectionModelChange={handleSelectionModelChange}
                        sx={{
                            "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
                                color: (theme) => theme.palette.text.primary,
                                background: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.light,
                                fontWeight: "bold !important"
                            },
                            '.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle': {
                                fontWeight: 'bold !important',
                                overflow: 'visible !important'
                            },
                        }}
                    />
                </Box>
            )}
        </Box>
    );
}



